# What's the best way to return the remaining of the sentence starting at 'connect'?

Tags: c#

Example:
Please make sure you have the connect TNSnames and SQLnet files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

str.SubString(str.IndexOf("connect"));

Answer (score 6):

A combination of `IndexOf`, `SubString` and checking that it exists to avoid an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`:

```
string input = "Please make sure you have the connect TNSnames and SQLnet files.";
int index = input.IndexOf("connect");
if (index != -1)
{
    string result = input.Substring(index);
}
```

Also, consider what happens if you have the word "connecting" instead of "connect" - is that a valid partial match or must you find the complete word? If you need the complete word you can use a word-boundary regex by placing your desired word between `\b` metacharacters:

```
Match m = Regex.Match(input, @"\bconnect\b.*$");
if (m.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
}
```

The `.*$` portion tells the regex to match any character (`.*`) till the end of the sentence (`$`).

If you really want the index you could omit the `.*$` part and use this (although this ignores the usefulness of regex, I am only pointing this out if you need the index for whatever reason):

```
Match m = Regex.Match(input, @"\bconnect\b");
if (m.Success)
{
    int index = m.Index;
    Console.WriteLine(input.Substring(index)); // Substring approach again
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
string input = "...";

input.Substring(input.IndexOf("connect"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably [Substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).